# Python logging automatically capture all the exception

Tags: python

Is there a way that automatically capture all the exceptions occurred through 'logging' module and write them into a .log file?

Please do not mention the solution that 'manually' writes traceback.format_exc() into the log

Comment: To get the text of a traceback, use `traceback.format_exc()`. You can then write the string to a log file if you'd like.